# Can I force Chrome window names to persist?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, macos-ventura

I use a lot of different Chrome windows simultaneously for different user profiles. I use the Name Window function daily to quickly identify which user I'm trying to get to from the dock.

[image]

[image]

Often I'll accidentally close the whole window instead of one tab, and it's a huge pain to have to rename everything all over again every time I close Chrome.

I've done a ton of digging and trying different extensions to find a way to permanently assign window names to specific user profiles and have had no luck. Is there a way I can set a window name associated with a user in (their profile data?) and make it persist, even when relaunching after Chrome is closed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to start Google Chrome with `Default` user profile and same window name :

```
#!/bin/bash

osascript << EOF
set userProfile to "Default"
set urlToOpen to "http://www.google.com" -- The URL to open in Chrome

set chromePath to "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
set commandToRun to quoted form of chromePath & " --profile-directory=" & quoted form of userProfile & " " & quoted form of urlToOpen
do shell script commandToRun
delay 1
tell application "Google Chrome"
    if not (exists window 1) then
        make new window
        set URL of active tab of window 1 to urlToOpen
        delay 1
    end if
    execute front window's active tab javascript "document.title = 'Default'"
end tell
EOF
```